# If the saturated ideal of hypersurface generated by one element?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If a subscheme of codimenion one in $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ is define by ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$, is the saturation $\oplus_{n\ge 0}\Gamma(I(n))\subseteq k[x_0,...,x_n]$ be generated by one element?

Is there a counterexample? Do we require the subscheme to be locally principal? (Is there a closed subschemem of projective space which is not locally principal?)

Comment: Wouldn't the closed subscheme defined by $(xy,xz)$ in $S = k[x,y,z]$ with $P^2 = Proj (S)$ work?

Comment: Youngsu: that subscheme is the union of two irreducible pieces, $(x)$ and $(y,z)$, only one of which is of codimension 1.